# How to debug Java agents (two headed beast approach) using org.openntf.domino API

Tags: java, lotus-domino

For a while there has been the two-headed beast way of debugging a java agent in Domino.
Description please refer to this thread:

[How to debug Java agents (two headed beast approach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950109/how-to-debug-java-agents-two-headed-beast-approach)

With the new API from openntf I'm stuck since there is no createSession() method anymore and I wonder how to do this?

Below is my "main":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session s = null;
        Database d = null;
        Database l = null;
        Database m = null;

        lotus.domino.NotesThread.sinitThread();
        try {

            s = NotesFactory.createSession((String) null,
                    (String) null, "mypassword");

            d = s.getDatabase("DeepThought/tradechannel",
                    "tradesec/7.0/tradesec.nsf");


            JavaAgent a = new JavaAgent(s, d);
            a.NotesMain();
        }
/**
 * This is only here for debugging purposes
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
public JavaAgent() {

}

/**
 * This is only here for debugging purposes
 * 
 * @param s
 *            Session
 * @param d
 *            Database
 * @param l
 *            Database
 */
public JavaAgent(Session s, Database d) {
    session = s;
    db = d;
}
public void NotesMain() {
            if (session != null) {
                session = session;
                db = db;
                logDb = logDb;
                agentName = "Archive Agent";
                alog = alog;
            } else {
                session = getSession();
                agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
                agentName = agentContext.getCurrentAgent().getName();
                db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();

            } 
}
```

I'm using Domino 9 HF441, org.openntf.domino.xsp_1.0.0.201309021740

Comment: You should probably put in your class details and where you do sTermThread().

Answer (score 0):

In org.openntf.domino.utils there is a Factory.getSession() method. If you use that it should give you an org.openntf.domino.Session rather than the lotus.domino.Session

Comment: The problem comes later when the debugger prompts me for a password of the ID-file used. This was circumvented using createSession().
Any ideas?

Comment: This may give you the answer http://nathantfreeman.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/running-openntf-domino-api-code-directly-from-eclipse/

Comment: I think I convert to remote debugging instead. Seems easier and the code is cleaner